# Reading objects from my array - Cannot use object of type XXXX as array

Tags: php, arrays, object

So I've got the following output;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 0
            [Nickname] => Alban_Berisha
            [Score] => 420
            [Ping] => 96
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 1
            [Nickname] => Flaviano_Villegas
            [Score] => 122
            [Ping] => 95
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 2
            [Nickname] => Tyrone_DeRozan
            [Score] => 0
            [Ping] => 120
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 3
            [Nickname] => Tage_Thomas
            [Score] => 3
            [Ping] => 246
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 4
            [Nickname] => Jamal_Williams
            [Score] => 149
            [Ping] => 149
        ) 
)
```

I want a list containing every PlayerID coupled with the Nickname, but I keep getting various errors. What is the correct way of doing this?
I have worked with arrays before but I cannot seem to extract the data from it without getting an error

One of the ways I've tried to do this;

```
    for(new $x=0; $x<5; $x++)
{
    echo (var_dump($array[$x]["PlayerID"])." ".var_dump($array[$x]["Nickname"]));
}
```

Comment: Show an example of the code you've tried and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What were you trying to do with `new x`?

```
<?php
$array = array(
            array('PlayerID' => 0,
                  'Nickname' => 'Alban_Berisha',
                  'Score' => 420,
                  'Ping' => 96
                  ),
            array('PlayerID' => 1,
                  'Nickname' => 'Flaviano_Villegas',
                  'Score' => 122,
                  'Ping' => 95
                  ),
            array('PlayerID' => 2,
                  'Nickname' => 'Tyrone_DeRozan',
                  'Score' => 0,
                  'Ping' => 120
                  ),
            array('PlayerID' => 3,
                  'Nickname' => 'Tage_Thomas',
                  'Score' => 3,
                  'Ping' => 246
                  ),
            array('PlayerID' => 4,
                  'Nickname' => 'Jamal_Williams',
                  'Score' => 149,
                  'Ping' => 149
                  )
            );
print_r($array); 
foreach($array as $arr){
    echo $arr['PlayerID'] .' '.$arr['Nickname'] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 0
            [Nickname] => Alban_Berisha
            [Score] => 420
            [Ping] => 96
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 1
            [Nickname] => Flaviano_Villegas
            [Score] => 122
            [Ping] => 95
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 2
            [Nickname] => Tyrone_DeRozan
            [Score] => 0
            [Ping] => 120
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 3
            [Nickname] => Tage_Thomas
            [Score] => 3
            [Ping] => 246
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [PlayerID] => 4
            [Nickname] => Jamal_Williams
            [Score] => 149
            [Ping] => 149
        )
)

0 Alban_Berisha
1 Flaviano_Villegas
2 Tyrone_DeRozan
3 Tage_Thomas
4 Jamal_Williams
```

Comment: That's it! I tried the for(x) to see if I could get the first 5 results, however it was far from right. I'm still studying on PHP so I  consider every mistake a useful one. Thank you for your answer, it helped me loads!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped. You were almost there, just remove 'new' and dont' use var_dump. `for($x=0; $x<5; $x++)
{
    echo ($array[$x]["PlayerID"]." ".$array[$x]["Nickname"]) ."<br/>";
}` Though in general, it's better to use foreach to loop through data arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP 5.5's new [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function

```
$newArray = array_column($originalArray, 'Nickname', 'PlayerID');
```

or with earlier versions of PHP:

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_map(
        function($value) { return $value['PlayerID']; },
        $originalArray
    ),
    array_map(
        function($value) { return $value['Nickname']; },
        $originalArray
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want a new array with player ID and nickname?

If so:

```
$ouputArray = array();

foreach ($oldArray as $player){
 $ouputArray[$player['PlayerID']] = $player['Nickname'];
}

print_r($outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();
foreach ($players as $player) {
    $results[ $player['PlayerID'] ] = $player['Nickname'];
}
```